# Change URL based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a variable passed from controller to view page and depending upon the variable format, I would like to append different URL's to be to the variable.

*If variable passed is numeric:*

**Eg:**
var_from_controller = 123456

**Expected Output:**
link_to "#{var_from_controller}", "https://google.com/{var_from_controller}", target: "_blank"

*If variable passed is Alpha-numeric:*

**Eg:**
var_from_controller = a31dwr123

**Expected Output:**
link_to "#{var_from_controller}", "https://facebook.com/{var_from_controller}", target: "_blank"

Comment: Isn't this as easy as an 'if' statement?

Comment: I'm new to ruby programming @jvillian, especially on the view part. Could you please help me with the format

Comment: I assume you're using `erb` (your view file ends in `.html.erb`)? It's really very basic. Try the [googles](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+erb+tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you CAN base the match on the variables Class, the danger is that if you pass the integer as a string, that still breaks.

```
> "1234".is_a? Integer
=> false
```

I would probably just use the matcher.  =~ is ruby's match operator, and !~ is the does-not-match operator.

#### Example

```
>  '123abccba321' !~ /\D/
=> false

> '123123123' !~ /\D/
=> true
```

And because @Srack is right, and a helper is ideal here I would base my answer off of that.

```
# app/helpers/your_helper.rb
 def link_to_social_url(string_var)
   if string_var !~ /\D/
     url = "https://facebook.com/#{string_var}"
   else
     url = "https://google.com/#{string_var}"
   end
   link_to string_var, url, target: "_blank"
 end
```

And in your view

```
<%= link_to_social_url(@var_from_controller) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example of one way you could do this - there are *many* ways you could structure the code, though I hope this provides a simple example and covers what you're asking in the question.

In your controller, set an instance variable - this will make it available to your view:

```
# app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def your_action
  @var_from_controller = "a31dwr123" 
  # ...
end
```

In order to keep the logic from your view, you may then want to employ a helper method to vary the URL:

```
# app/helpers/your_helper.rb
def link_to_social_url(path)
  url = case path
        when String
          "https://facebook.com/#{var_from_controller}"
        when Integer
          "https://google.com/#{var_from_controller}"
        else
          # a fallback if you want one
        end

  link_to path, url, target: "_blank"
end
```

Then you can use this in your view:

```
<!-- your_view.html.erb -->
<%= link_to_social_url(@var_from_controller) %>
```

Hope that helps with setting this up and a very basic structure for this. Give me a shout to let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

Because changing the URL is a matter of "business logic" it is conventional to do this work wholly in the controller:

```
@url_data = # wherever your numeric or alphanumeric data is coming from
if @url_data.class == Integer
  @url = "https://google.com/#{@url_data}"
else
  @url = "https://facebook.com/#{@url_data}"
end
```

Then, in the view:

```
link_to @url_data, @url, target: "_blank"
```

However, I think you might also want to consider that writing a conditional statement based on data class or type is often a bad idea. Perhaps your seemingly-numeric data will take the form of a string at times. Perhaps your seemingly alphanumeric data will occasionally appear without any letters. These situations will break the code.

It's likely that the URL should be conditional on some aspect of where your data is coming from, rather than just the format.